Using different Python versions between projects
I am using different versions of python for different projects. I don't want to keep changing all the environment variables, my path and restarting my ides each time. What is the generally agreed way to flick between these on different projects.
For context I am using pycharm and when configuring interpreter and using the terminal I feel I have to make the interpreter and the system version the same.
Any insights would be appreciated
Changing environment variables each time I want to change projects

virtual environments, docker containers, conda envs... take your pick
